# Candle snakes - strange candle behavior

Tags: everyday-life, phase-transition

I was fidgeting with a candle when I started noticing that some strings of candle were forming in the liquid (see attached picture, where one of them was removed).

I tried seeing if there was any info online, but couldn't find anything describing this phenomenon. The strings are gooey and sticky, with a different consistent than the semi-hard wax.

I'm wondering if this is like chocolate tempering, where in some particular heating-cooling conditions you get different textures.

This is a scented candle, so another hypothesis could be that the scent is being separated.

Since it relates to a household item, I assume this is documented somewhere, does anyone know what's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at melting candles with google, the "string form" is dominant in the pictures, and I chose [this one](https://rare-gallery.com/uploads/posts/4512787-fingers-closeup-photography-depth-of-field-candles-fire-burning-wax-melting-simple-background.jpg) :

[image: candle wax]

The simplest explanation is that due a)the cohesion of the wax , b)  the texture and temperature of the surface on which the wax is flowing while melting,  the wax coagulates to a string form. In your particular candle the simplest explanation is that they kept their form within the melted wax due to differences in pressure and temperature.